# Show $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x^{\frac{2-n}{2}}(\ln x)^{-\frac{2+n}{2}}=0$ for $n\geq 3$

Tags: calculus, limits

Show $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{1+x})^{\frac{n+2}{2}}x^2=\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x^{\frac{2-n}{2}}(\ln x)^{-\frac{2+n}{2}}=0$ for $n\geq 3$.

The first limit is zero for sure since the highest power of the denominator is higher than numerator. But why are the two limits equal and why is the second limit zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the second limit is $0$, it is enough to show that,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(\ln x)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}= \infty \ \ \ \forall \ n\geq 3 $$

Now note that, $(\ln x)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}\geq (\ln x)^2 $ for $n\geq 3$ and $x\geq e$

Also, $x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}\geq \sqrt{x} $ for $x\geq 1$ so each of this individual terms converge to infinity separetly. Hence so does their product.

Comment: Why are the two limits equal? (without thinking their limits both being zero for a moment)

Comment: @Fei, You first show that each of the limits is 0 and then conclude that they are equal. Why would you not want to use something we have already proved?